# Where can I find a basic algorithm for parsing tiled maps?

Tags: c++, maps

I have attempted to use Tiled for creating 2d maps, and saving them under a text file. The resulting text file seems difficult to parse at first, I gave it a shot [here](http://paste2.org/p/2372379) however to no good result.

I have been wondering if anyone has a basic tiled map parsing algorithm. I have searched for a possible algorithm but to no avail so far.

Comment: You can probably write your own export format, you just need to make the first set number of file bytes store your width/height and then store byte codes for each tile type (grass = 0x01, water = 0x02, etc.) It's a bit more difficult, but I prefer to do things in a way that give me complete control over them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the txt export option of Tiled is a format used by one specific engine. Copying that format might not be the best solution for your use-case.

I would recommend you to save your Tiled maps in the native TMX format and parse it with an XML parser like libXML. The JSON export is also an option, but I have never worked with any JSON library in C++, so I can't recommend you one.

[Open source code which loads TMX maps with libXML2](https://github.com/mana/mana/blob/master/src/resources/mapreader.cpp) can be found in the sourcecode of the client of the open source MMORPG *[The Mana World](http://themanaworld.org/)*. By the way: The lead developer of Tiled is also participating in the development of TMW.

Full Disclosure: I used to be a developer of TMW myself and wrote a few lines of the code linked above.

Comment: That's an excellent example. I didn't think of XML parsing yet as it seems game developers tend to avoid it. If no more answers will come up I will also accept the question :)

Comment: By the way: all the `XML::*` helper functions which are used all over that code are implemented here: https://github.com/mana/mana/blob/master/src/utils/xml.cpp